# Iteratively Calculate output from String '6*5+2/8' using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know if we use directly use in select statement it will work

select (6*5+2/4) from dual;

This will produce output 30.5 but my expectation is
6*5 = 30 + 2 = 32 / 4 = 8
it should return 8

is there a way to do calculation like this?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong.  You need to go back and review your basic math, particularly order of operations.  you work from left to right, performing all multiplication and division. Then and only then go back and work from left to right, performing all addition and subtraction.  If there are operations enclosed in parentheses, apply the same rules within the parentheses first.  Again, this is a fundamental rule of math.

Comment: Thanks for details but the requirement is to do calculation from left to right and not follow the BODMAS rule, and do the calculation manually or write generic query.
I could have tried substr and instr for fixed string, if any of the mathematical operators change their position then it will not work

Comment: @nagraj036 If you need to override operator order of precedence, you need to add brackets yourself. In your case, around every single operation... `(((6*5)+2)/4)` There is no native support for doing that, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: _"the requirement is to do calculation from left to right and not follow the BODMAS rule"_  Then the "requirement" is to come up with a mathematically _INCORRECT_ solution.  Of what value is that?

Comment: Do you have only "simple" operations or there may be some function calls/power etc?

Comment: OK - so the input is a string like `'6*5+2/4'` (you added the totally useless parentheses around the **whole** expression yourself, for no reason) - and the task is to compute the result, executing all operations left to right, giving all operations the same precedence? If so, then that can be done in a few ways (for example using an XQuery expression) after modifying the input string first. Question though - How are you showing negative inputs? For example (-3)*(-2); is that shown as the input `-3*-2`? Or perhaps using parentheses **only** for negative numbers and nothing else?

Comment: For example the input could be `'6*(-5)+2/(-4)'`. Or are you only looking for help on expressions with non-negative inputs? Also - will there only be integers, or could you have decimals also, and if so, in what format? Will they always look like 0.33 for example, or do you allow .33 as well (no leading 0)? How about scientific notation - can an operand be 2.32e3 (meaning the number 2320)?

Comment: @mathguy There are only positive integers, yes I am looking if it is possible to give same precedence for all 4 operators (+, -, *, /) and execute from left to right. I will look for XQuery Expression

Comment: @EdStevens I am not going to implement this in Real world, I am trying to find if there is a way to write SQL query or PLSQL function to get the this type of output. I think we can implement in JAVA by writing our own parser. I am sorry if the question framed is not right

Comment: @nagraj036 - The solution I gave uses somebody else's parser (the one in XQuery). A much more interesting question is to write our own parser (without using XQuery, or the possible alternative of a dynamic SQL `select` statement in PL/SQL), using standard arithmetic rules - allowing negative and decimal numbers, standard operator precedence, parentheses, function calls, etc. It can be done - obviously, easier in PL/SQL. I've been working on something like that already (and other solutions exist on github and elsewhere). We may need to implement our own "stack" structure first, etc.

Comment: @nagraj036 There's at least one open source PL/SQL program for evaluating expression - maybe the project [PLCalc](https://github.com/mbleron/PLCalc) could be a useful starting point if you need a robust implementation. (Also, I'm not sure why this question is getting so much hate. People act like God created the order of operations, but it's just a convention that most people follow. Many systems use a different order of operations, and sometimes we have to imitate those systems.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution below assumes all inputs are non-negative integers, there are no parentheses and no spaces in the input expression, and there is no division by zero.

If the input has parentheses, those can be removed first. If there are spaces, they can be removed first too. If the inputs may include fractional numbers and/or negative numbers, that can be accommodated too, with a bit more work.

The strategy: first insert parentheses to force the order of evaluation; this is shown in the `new_str` intermediate result (in the `prep` subquery). We also need to change '/' to ' div ' for use in XQuery.

Then just use XQuery to evaluate the resulting arithmetic expression string.

```
with
  test_data (str) as (
    select '6*5+2/4'    from dual union all
    select '332'        from dual union all
    select '12+3*5/75'  from dual
  )
, prep (str, new_str) as (
    select str,
           replace(
             rpad('(', length(regexp_replace(str, '\d')), '(') ||
             regexp_replace(str, '([-+*/])', ')\1')
             , '/', ' div ')
    from   test_data
  )
select str, new_str,
       xmlcast(xmlquery(new_str returning content) as number) as result
from   prep;

STR        NEW_STR               RESULT
---------  -------------------  -------
6*5+2/4    (((6)*5)+2) div 4          8
332        332                      332
12+3*5/75  (((12)+3)*5) div 75        1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive query:

```sql
WITH perform_calculation (value, calculation) AS (
  SELECT value,
         value
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         CASE REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2)
         WHEN '+' THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
                       +
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 3)
         WHEN '-' THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
                       -
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 3)
         WHEN '*' THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
                       *
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 3)
         WHEN '/' THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
                       /
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 3)
         END
         || REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 4)
  FROM   perform_calculation
  WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) IS NOT NULL
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET value_order
SELECT value,
       calculation
FROM   perform_calculation
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(calculation, '^(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+*/-])(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) IS NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '6*5+2/4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '6*5+2/4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '32/4*3/2+24/4+3/6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3/2-3*5' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | CALCULATION |
> | --- | --- |
> | 3/2-3*5 | -7.5 |
> | 32/4*3/2+24/4+3/6 | 2 |
> | 6*5+2/4 | 8 |
> | 6*5+2/4 | 8 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=236bdfff7774c50de9291ed9e5092af4)*

Answer (score 0):

Division takes precedent over addition so your calculation, by default, will be:

(6*5)+(2/4)

If you want to change the default precedence then you need to use brackets:

(6*5+2)/4

Comment: this will work only for this condition, I am looking for generic query and mathematical operators can change their positions

Comment: You either aren’t explaining your issue very well or you don’t understand basic mathematical operator precedence. Any sequence of numbers and operators will be evaluated using standard operator precedence. If you want some different precedence to be used then you need to implement it using brackets - but obviously that would only apply to a specific instance, there is no way of changing the default operator precedence that a DBMS would use for all maths equations